# Count not empty textboxes using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I wish to count the number of textboxes that's been filled. I have the following code but it's not working the way I want it too. I'm new to JQuery and the script is based from my research here on Stack Overflow.

Markup:

```
<input class="a" type="text" name="rep">
<input class="a" type="text" name="rep">
<input class="a" type="text" name="rep">
```

Script:

```
$(".a").blur(alert(countRep()));

function countRep() {
    var fieldTxtbx = $(".a").filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).val()) != '';
    }).length;
    return fieldTxtbx;
}
```

Why does it work the on load but everytime I input in the textbox the `blur()` is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are binding the return value of `countRep()` with blur event which is not a function.

bind a function with event and call your method.

```
$(".a").blur(function() {
    alert(countRep())
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, if it's okay, now I'm using it in a condition but why doesn't it return any value? `$('[name=attendance]:checked').length + countRep >= 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(".a").blur(alert(countRep()));
```

With this:

```
$(".a").blur(alert(countRep)); // no needed to use parenthesis to call function.
```

Or, use like this:

```
$(".a").blur(function(){
  alert(countRep());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your blur event to:

```
$(".a").blur(function(){
 alert(countRep());
});
```

also you can use narrow down selector for non empty textboxes to:

```
$('.a').filter(function() {
   return $(this).val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of the first line:

```
'$(".a").on("blur", OnBlur);

function OnBlur(event) {
  alert(countRep);
}
```